# Flash ActionScript2 key listener specific to input?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, keylistener

I have 2 user inputs in my flash banner, I also have a code that allows the user to submit using the "enter" key. However, currently this code is global, meaning that if I hit "enter" it fires the same code regardless of what input is in focus:

```
keyListener = new Object();

keyListener.onKeyDown = function(){
    if(Key.isDown(Key.ENTER)){
        // do something
    }
}

Key.addListener(keyListener);
```

How can I modify this code so that different actions are fired depending on which of the 2 inputs are focused?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting a focus listener to remember which of those inputs has focus, then checking that from your onKeyDown handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the `Selection` class which allows you to get and set focus to any object on your scene, with the [getFocus](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001499.html) method:

```
keyListener = new Object();

keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {
    if (Key.isDown(Key.ENTER)) {
        // trace(Selection.getFocus());
        if (Selection.getFocus() == "_level0.input1") /* do something */;
        if (Selection.getFocus() == "_level0.input2") /* do something else */; 
    }
}

Key.addListener(keyListener);
```